# Got daemonp error while installing doom

Tags: macos, bash, git, emacs

I am on Macos 10.14 and am trying to install Doom with Emacs.

I've downloaded emacs with `brew install --cask emacs`, and it is at version `GNU Emacs 27.2`.

I run the installation lines per [doom's documentation](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs),

```bsh
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs ~/.emacs.d
~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install
```

And I get this error inside of emacs:

```
("emacs" "--no-site-file" "--script" "/Users/rj/.emacs.d/bin/doom" "--" "install")
Loading encoded-kb...done


An error has occurred while loading `/Users/rj/.emacs.d/init.el':

Symbol's function definition is void: daemonp

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

command-line-1: Unknown option `--script'
```

I'm trying to get started with emacs, so I appreciate any pointers people have.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Doom installation guide for emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/docs/getting_started.org), you should not install using any of these:

```bsh
emacsformacosx.com
brew cask install emacs (installs from emacsformacosx.com)
AquaMacs
XEmacs
```

I installed with `brew cask install emacs`, which caused this issue.

You may want to check `which emacs` to make sure that it is pointing to the correct application.

Installing emacs-mac worked for me:

```bsh
brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport
brew install emacs-mac --with-modules
ln -s /usr/local/opt/emacs-mac/Emacs.app /Applications/Emacs.app
```

There is an emacs at /usr/bin/emacs that otherwise has precedence, and I can't edit/remove it without disabling [system integrity protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled).

I added `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/emacs-mac/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.bashrc`, so that the correct emacs was recognized, and doom now works as expected.